# Naming an algorithm for comparing two sorted lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got an [algorithm that compares two sorted lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161432/best-algorithm-for-synchronizing-two-ilist-in-c-2-0/161535#161535), and I'm planning to make it more LINQ-y.

My first question: is there anything like this in LINQ already?

If not, I'm planning on writing it as an extension method, something like this:

```
public static class SortedCompareExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Pair<T, U>>
        CompareTo<T,U>(this IEnumerable<T> left,
                       IEnumerable<U> right,
                       Func<T, U, int> comparison)
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

It'll return `new Pair<T, U>(t, u)` if both elements are equivalent, `new Pair<T, U>(t, null)` if the element only exists in the left-hand list, etc.

My second question: `CompareTo` is not a great name for this. What is it? Is it comparing, collating, correlating? What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [Synchronizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_synchronization) the lists, though the name has unfortunate connotations of thread synchronization.

I would say that 'ReconcileOrdered' (perhaps OrderedReconcile) is a reasonable name (it is probably very important to indicate in the function's name that the arguments must both be ordered for it to behave correctly

Comment: I like 'Reconcile'. I think I'll go with OrderedReconcileWith().

Answer (score 1):

How about `Diff`? I don't believe there's anything already in LINQ to do everything, but there's [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) and [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx). It sounds like your code is mostly a mixture of the two - except those are *set* operations, whereas you've got sorted lists. It that mostly a case of efficiency, or is there a semantic difference in your case? (One example would be repeated entries.)

Personally I'm not sure I'd use a pair in this case. There's only ever one value involved, isn't there? Isn't it really a case of Value, PresentInLeft (bool) and PresentInRight (bool)? I'm sure each representation has its pros and cons, and you can certainly expose either API from the same underlying data...

Comment: It's for efficiency. The IEnumerable<T> might actually live on the other side of a network connection (returned from a server), and might be quite large, so I generate them in coroutines.

Comment: Even if a value appears in both lists, it might still need synchronising (e.g. if only comparing by one or two properties, the other properties might need reconciling), so I need both.

Comment: Okay, so it's only a sorted of projected equivalence, rather than equivalence of the whole entity. That's fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

That algorithm that is linked, is very close to a "Full Outer Merge Join".  It differs only in how duplicates are treated.

> is there anything like this in LINQ already?
>
> It'll return new Pair(t, u) if both elements are equivalent, new Pair(t, null) if the element only exists in the left-hand list, etc.

From left side only, [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx) is similiar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I end up with. I quite like it, particularly the selector that means that the caller can decide what to return in each scenario:

```
public static class OrderedReconcileExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult>
        ReconcileWith<T, U, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> left,
                                     IEnumerable<U> right,
                                     Func<T, U, int> comparison,
                                     Func<T, U, TResult> selector)
    {
        return ReconcileHelper(new EnumerableIterator<T>(left),
                               new EnumerableIterator<U>(right),
                               comparison, selector);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TResult>
        ReconcileHelper<T, U, TResult>(EnumerableIterator<T> left,
                                       EnumerableIterator<U> right,
                                       Func<T, U, int> comparison,
                                       Func<T, U, TResult> selector)
    {
        while (left.IsValid && right.IsValid)
        {
            // While left < right, the items in left aren't in right
            while (left.IsValid && right.IsValid && 
                   comparison(left.Current, right.Current) < 0)
            {
                yield return selector(left.Current, default(U));
                left.MoveNext();
            }

            // While right < left, the items in right aren't in left
            while (left.IsValid && right.IsValid &&
                   comparison(left.Current, right.Current) > 0)
            {
                yield return selector(default(T), right.Current);
                right.MoveNext();
            }

            // While left == right, the items are in both
            while (left.IsValid && right.IsValid &&
                   comparison(left.Current, right.Current) == 0)
            {
                yield return selector(left.Current, right.Current);
                left.MoveNext();
                right.MoveNext();
            }
        }

        // Mop up.
        while (left.IsValid)
        {
            yield return selector(left.Current, default(U));
            left.MoveNext();
        }

        while (right.IsValid)
        {
            yield return selector(default(T), right.Current);
            right.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

`EnumerableIterator` is exactly the same as in the code I posted in the other question.

*Update: "exactly the same" apart from IsValid is changed to HasCurrent. Pick one.*